# How to delete data from one nested array if it matches with the other array ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I need to remove an nested array if it matches the id of the main array.

arrayOne =

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "role": [
            "pos_cashier_1",
            "pos_manager"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "role": [
            "pos_manager",
            "pos_cashier_2"
        ]
    }
]
```

arrayTwo

```
[
    {
        "label": "Sessions Sandringham",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sessions West Brunswick",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "label": "Global",
        "value": null
    }
]
```

I need to remove the arrays in the arrayTwo if its value == id in the arrayOne.
Can someone help me...

Comment: I don't know why the title mentions "nested array". It doesn't seem necessary since we're not using a nested array for the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a `Set` of all the ids in the first array, then filter the second array based on the existence of the value property in that `Set`.

```js
let arr1=[{id:"1",role:["pos_cashier_1","pos_manager"]},{id:"2",role:["pos_manager","pos_cashier_2"]}],arr2=[{label:"Sessions Sandringham",value:"1"},{label:"Sessions West Brunswick",value:"2"},{label:"Global",value:null}];
let ids = new Set(arr1.map(o => o.id));
let res = arr2.filter(x => !ids.has(x.value));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to create a set of ids first, but you can also do it as a one-liner using `find` like this:

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":"1","role":["pos_cashier_1","pos_manager"]},{"id":"2","role":["pos_manager","pos_cashier_2"]}]
const arr2 = [{"label":"Sessions Sandringham","value":"1"},{"label":"Sessions West Brunswick","value":"2"},{"label":"Global","value":null}]

console.log(arr2.filter(({value:v})=>!arr1.some(({id})=>id===v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using `find` and `filter`

```
const arr1 = [{"id":"1","role":["pos_cashier_1","pos_manager"]},{"id":"2","role":["pos_manager","pos_cashier_2"]}]
const arr2 = [{"label":"Sessions Sandringham","value":"1"},{"label":"Sessions West Brunswick","value":"2"},{"label":"Global","value":null}]

let output = arr2.filter(d => d.value == arr1.find(info => info.id == d.value))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Your current code would fail if there's `id`:`null` in `arr1`. It only works now because `filter` condition compares a string to an object. And `find` returns `undefined` when it doesn't have a match, but `d.value`(*from `arr2`*) is `null`,so the `filter` condition is: `null == undefined` which with *type conversion* equals to `true` so filters *in* the element. But fails to compare `null` to object. Since `filter` method requires a callback to return Boolean `true` or `false` you can simplify that to use just the opposite of what `find` returns using the logical NOT operator: `!arr1.find(...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `some` like this:

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "role": [
      "pos_cashier_1",
      "pos_manager"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "role": [
      "pos_manager",
      "pos_cashier_2"
    ]
  }
];

const arrayTwo = [
  {
    "label": "Sessions Sandringham",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "label": "Sessions West Brunswick",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "label": "Global",
    "value": null
  }
];
const filtered = arrayTwo.filter(({ value }) => !arrayOne.some(({ id }) => id === value));
console.log(filtered)
```